# Cannot run first cucumber feature using capybara on Windows 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, windows-8.1, railsinstaller

I am trying to create a first cucumber feature on Windows 8.1.

I installed Ruby using RailsInstaller.

```
rails --version
Rails 4.0.0
```

ruby -v gives

```
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]
```

gem list includes

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
::::
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.0.4
bundler (1.3.5)
capybara (2.3.0)
::
ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
gherkin (2.12.2 x86-mingw32)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9, 0.6.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
::
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0)
railties (4.0.0)
rake (10.3.2, 0.9.6)
rb-readline (0.5.0)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.0.0)
rspec (3.0.0)
rspec-core (3.0.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.0, 2
rspec-mocks (3.0.0)
rspec-support (3.0.0)
rubyzip (1.1.4, 0.9.9)
sass (3.2.19, 3.2.9)
sass-rails (4.0.3, 4.0.0)
sdoc (0.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.42.0)

**env.rb conta**ins
require 'capybara-screenshot'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'fileutils'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

If I run cucumber -v with an env.rb file I get the following error:

```
features/support/env.rb
cannot load such file -- capybara-screenshot (LoadError)****
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
<PATH/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
```

Without an env.rb I get the following:

```
::
  Scenario: To prove that *Country* is selected by default
    Given I visit the Home Page
      undefined method `visit' for #<Object:0x27bb488> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/<filename>.rb:2:in `/^I visit the Home Page$/'
      features\<filename>..feature:7:in `Given I visit the Home Page'

:::::
7 scenarios (7 failed)
19 steps (7 failed, 2 skipped, 10 undefined)
0m1.092s
```

**It looks like it does not understand the visit command.**

I am sure it is a configuration or PATH issue because when I

```
bundle exec
Could not locate Gemfile

cucumber --version
1.3.15
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.